# How can I assign event handler to event known from EventInfo?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, events

I would like to iterate over all events which a control (e.g. TextBox) supports and programmatically assign the same diagnostic event handler to each.

It is clear I cannot use C# `+=` or VB `AddHandler` command. How can I assign event handler to each event known from `GetType(TextBox).GetEvents()`?

```vb
Imports System.Reflection

Public Class Form1

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()

        For Each ei As EventInfo In GetType(TextBox).GetEvents()
            'AddHandler TextBox1.ei, AddressOf DiagnosticHandler - PLEASE HELP ME HERE
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub DiagnosticHandler(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        'whatever
    End Sub

End Class
```

(C# or VB - whatever you prefer.)

Comment: Reflection might work. I forget which, but it either requires `.NET4 or 4.5` for supporting event handlers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### [`EventInfo` type has `AddEventHandler()` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.eventinfo.addeventhandler(v=vs.100).aspx) exactly for this purpose.

Compatibility: **.NET 3.5** and higher (Tested.)

Minimal valid code:

```vb
Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent() ' needed only in Form class
    BindHandlers(TextBox1) ' this is our binding
End Sub

Public Sub BindHandlers(c As Control)
    Dim handler As MethodInfo = Me.GetType().GetMethod(NameOf(DiagnosticEventHandler))
    For Each ei In c.GetType().GetEvents()
        ei.AddEventHandler(c, [Delegate].CreateDelegate(ei.EventHandlerType, handler))
    Next
End Sub

Public Shared Sub DiagnosticEventHandler(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    'whatever
End Sub
```

**Note:** I only succeeded with `Public Shared` handler method. With `Private` and non-shared method I was getting signature compatibility errors which I was lazy to resolve.

Bonus for those who kept reading until this point:

```vb
Public Shared Sub DiagnosticEventHandler(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    'heuristic disclosing of method related to event name
    Dim maxAttempts As Integer = 15
    Dim attempt As Integer = 1
    Dim stackTrace As New StackTrace()
    Do While attempt <= maxAttempts
        Dim methodName As String = stackTrace.GetFrame(attempt).GetMethod().Name
        attempt += 1
        If methodName.StartsWith("On") Then
            Debug.Print(String.Join(" > ", stackTrace.GetFrames().Take(attempt).Skip(1).Select(Of String)(Function(sf) sf.GetMethod.Name).Reverse().ToArray()))
            Return
        End If
    Loop
    Debug.Print(String.Join(" > ", stackTrace.GetFrames().Take(maxAttempts).Select(Of String)(Function(sf) sf.GetMethod.Name).Reverse().ToArray()))
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone need it, here is the code to accomplish that (assuming you have a `TextBox` called textBox1 in the form).

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MethodInfo miHandler = typeof(Form1).GetMethod("DiagnosticHandler", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

        EventInfo[] events = typeof(TextBox).GetEvents();

        foreach (EventInfo ei in events)
        {
            Type tDelegate = ei.EventHandlerType;
            Delegate d = Delegate.CreateDelegate(tDelegate, this, miHandler);
            MethodInfo addHandler = ei.GetAddMethod();
            Object[] addHandlerArgs = { d };
            addHandler.Invoke(this.textBox1, addHandlerArgs);
        }

    }

    private void DiagnosticHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //whatever
    }
}
```

more info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228976(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: C# guys will thank you. :) Also, in latest Roslyn you can avoid unfortunate `"DiagnosticHandler"` string and use ellegant `NameOf()` operator instead (used in my VB answer).